# Trying to Create a Login Method but the password in my MySql database is hashed, also using a self made dataProvider in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, registration

So i have created a register page that will take your first name, last name, email and a password and stores it inside my database,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register_User]

@FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
@LastName NVARCHAR(100),
@Password NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Email NVARCHAR(100),
@Id INT OUTPUT

AS

INSERT INTO UserFromFrontEnd
(FirstName, LastName, [Password], Email)
VALUES
(@FirstName, @LastName, @Password, @Email)

SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and in Visual Studios I have created this method

```
public int Register(RegisterRequest model)
        {
            int newId = 0;
            string pwdToHash = model.Password + "^Y8~JJ";
            string hashToStoreInDatabase = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pwdToHash, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt());
            _dataProvider.ExecuteNonQuery(
                "Register_User",
                (parameters) =>
                {      
                    parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", model.FirstName);
                    parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", model.LastName);
                    parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", model.Email);
                    parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", hashToStoreInDatabase);

                    parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                },
                (parameters) =>
                {
                    newId = (int)parameters["@Id"].Value;
                }
                );
            return newId;
        }
```

this method takes the input from the front end and stores it inside my database while at the same time hashing the password using Bcrypt.Net-Next
Now i have created a login procedure that as such

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoginFromFrontEnd]


@Email NVARCHAR(100),
@Password NVARCHAR(100)

AS

SELECT Email, [Password]
FROM
UserFromFrontEnd
WHERE
Email=@Email AND [Password]=@Password
```

now i am trying to create the login method

```
public string Login(LoginUser model)
        {
            _dataProvider.ExecuteCmd(
                "LoginFromFrontEnd",
                (parameters) => 
                {
                    parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", model.Email);
                },
                (reader, recordSetIndex) =>
                {
                    LoginUser _login = Mapper(reader);
                }
                );
        }

private LoginUser Mapper(IDataReader reader)
        {
            LoginUser login = new LoginUser();
            login.Email = reader["Email"] as string;
            login.Password = reader["Password"] as string;
            return login;
        }
```

but i am unsure on how to first unhash the password and then check to see if it matches the one in my database

Comment: Why don't use hash the new password to see if it matches the value in the database instead of trying to unhash the existing password?

Comment: The idea of a hash is not to be reversible, if it was unhasheable it wouldnt complete its purpose, The way to test is is like simply ged says, send the hash and compare both, if both matches then it works, since a hash is unique

Comment: i understand that but i'm trying to see it from the user's perspective. If i was a user on a website and i registered an email with a password, my C# code will hash up the password and store that into my database, but when the user logs in he's not gonna be able to enter his hashed up password, he's gonna enter the password that he registered with, but as of right now i don't have a login method that'll be able to match the user's input password with the hashed up password. So as of right now my sql is unable to match Password with @Password

Comment: If you hash their entered password using the same method as what you used when they signed up, the hashes will be the same. Then just compare the hashes. You should never de-hash a hashed password.